# Merlin complains about a missing module in the same project

Tags: emacs, ocaml, utop, merlin

I am new to Ocaml and just setting up my dev environment with emacs, merlin and flycheck. Everything works more or less expected except one thing : merlin doesn't seem to be able recognise the dependencies between the modules in the same project.

e.g. I have a test project with two modules: main.ml and awesome.ml.

here is my main.ml which references the second module awesome.ml

```
(* main.ml *)
open Core
module A = Awesome
let _ =
   Printf.printf "hello \n Converted to string we get: %s\n"
     (A.str_of_t (A.succ A.one_t));
```

here is awesome.ml:

```
(* awesome.ml *) 
type t = int
let one_t = 1
let succ i = i + 1
let str_of_t = string_of_int
```

when I send main.ml buffer to evaluate into utop with utop-eval-buffer function, I am getting an error: "Error: Unbound module Awesome"

I have .merlin in the root of the project which has S instruction.
I know it is found by merlin as it doesn't complain about "open Core"

```
S src
PKG core lwt ounit
B _build/src
B +threads
```

here is my _tags:

```
<src/**>: include
<src/**>: package(oUnit), package(core)
true:thread
```

the regular project compilation with ocamlbuild works fine, no errors.
here is Makefile

```
## Makefile
default: main
main: main.native

test: test.native

%.native:
   ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind $@
   mv $@ $*

.PHONY: test default
```

any ideas why Awesome module is not recognised in utop or this is expected behaviour?

Answer (score 14):

Merlin will see other modules once you have compiled them (in fact, once you have compiled its interfaces). So given your `.merlin` is correct it will see everything after you run compilation.  Your files should indeed be in a `src` folder, i.e., your project layout, based on your `.merlin` file should look like this:

```
Makefile
.merlin
src/
   awesome.ml
   main.ml
```

This is not a required layout, but this is the one, that you described to Merlin. The reason, why I suspect that it is not the same, is your `Makefile`.

P.S. Just as a side note, there is a small issue in your code: you should open `Core.Std` not `Core`.

Comment: thanks Ivan. It still doesn't work. I have a correct project layout - the sources are in src dir, .merlin is in the root of the project. The reason for B +thread directive is here : https://github.com/the-lambda-church/merlin, I added as suggested in merlin docs. You are right about open Core.Std.  I ran the compilation - the sources compile correctly, I see o files in _build/src but merlin still doesn't recognise the awesome.ml module. Looks like something is wrong with my setup - I will keep digging. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect, that you have problems, with your makefile, and it doesn't compile anything. So, without a `Makefile`  file, if I will just go to the top directory of your project and issue `ocamlbuild src/main.native`, then merlin recognizes `Awesome` module. Basically, you `Makefile` looks incorrect to me. And it just do not compile anything. A good check: there should be `_build/src/awesome.cmi` file after running build.

Comment: nope, makefile is good - it compiles, produces a binary main which I can execute. awesome.cmi/awesome.cmo/awesome.cmt/awesome.cmti/awesome.cmxare  generated in _build/src

Comment: Well, then the next guess would be, that your emacs is somehow misconfigured. Look carefully, for the messages from emacs. The easiest way to run it without a problem is to run emacs from a terminal in which you previously run `eval $(opam config env)`

Comment: thanks, I will check my emacs setup. much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As [Ivan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31502206/90511) pointed out, Merlin can only recognize a module in your project after you compile it. If Merlin is giving you an `unbound module Foo` error, one solution is to run

```
ocamlbuild foo.cmi
```

Comment: This actually completely fixed it for me and I have no idea why. Does ocamlbuild somehow save state? I'm pretty new, so it's entirely possible that I just am very ignorant of how the whole dev environment works hah

Comment: Ocamlbuild will save the "foo.cmi" interface file inside the "_build" directory. Which I guess counts as "saving state".

Comment: Ohhh makes sense. I assumed Merlin was looking at the second and not built files I guess. Guess I was wrong!

Comment: Very odd… I got the same problem, but compiling the CMIs didn’t solve it. 

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I tried installing merlin through opam or sources, but I couldn't solve this problem until I put the ".merlin" file in to the \src directory--not at the root-- with a "REC" tag in it.

Comment: I did the same, but Merlin keeps complaining about modules that are there. One of two: there are magical undocumented settings; or there are annoying bugs.